# VBA Run-time error '424 on simple IF statement

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I have the following short VBA code, what I want is for it to check a cell, B5 for whether it is a Y or a N, and if Y - go to one macro, and if N - go to another macro.

```
Sub LoadSetup()

Dim Master As Workbook
Set SingleLoad = Setup.Range("B5")

If SingleLoad = "Y" Then
Call LatestLoad
Else
Call TimeSeriesLoad
End If

End Sub
```

I am getting a Run-rime error '424' Object Required on this line. Any ideas please what could be causing this?

```
Set SingleLoad = Setup.Range("B5")
```

Comment: What is `Setup`? If it's not the codename of a worksheet (not the tab caption), or a variable that has been assigned elsewhere, your code won't work.

Comment: hmm, Setup is what i have named the sheet in the tab. If i replace with ActiveSheet in my code it works. Thats strange i have never had this issue before...

Comment: Instead of `ActiveSheet`, use `Worksheets("Setup")`.  It is almost always more robust to use the actual worksheet name, and avoid relying on the sheet to have been activated.